# How can I use an extended jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I use a jQuery plugin called [ColorPicker](http://www.eyecon.ro/colorpicker/).

The source that I include is [here](http://lineupbuilder.com/rsrc/js/jquery-plugins/colorpicker/js/colorpicker.js).

So, my code is just `$("#some_id").ColorPicker(some_options)`, as indicated in the doc and it works fine.

But now, I want to use only one function from the source, `function HexToHSB()`, but I do not know how to use it as I do not completely understand jQuery plugins import.

I tried `$.ColorPicker.HexToHSB()` but it did nothing.

Comment: Do the other methods work?

Comment: do you get some error?

Comment: @KyleEmmanuel No.
@BeNdErR No, I do not see error in the console.log (but I know it does not work because I write `alert("start")` before (displayed) and `alert("end")` after (not displayed).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would not be able to do this as these functions are private to the module ColorPicker and you do not have access to them. This is how you can understand the plugin to be working:

```
// ColorPicker is an object with public methods, but no access to the private variables and functions in it.
// The function is being invoked at runtime, returning an object
var ColorPicker = function(){
  var privateVariables;
  var privateFunction = function(){...};
  ...
  return {
    publicFunction1 = function(){...},
    publicFunction2 = function(){...},
  }
}();

// jQuery is extended here
$.fn.extend({
    ColorPicker: ColorPicker.publicFunction1,
    ColorPicker: ColorPicker.publicFunction2,
});
```

There are two ways to fix your problem:

1. Copy the relevant functions out from that jQuery library and use them
2. Add code to the jQuery library to expose the private functions (e.g. add a custom function to line 375 that calls HexToHSB() and then extend jQuery with this function in line 478)